# Почему бы не включить сниппеты на мете?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение, статус-завершено, сниппеты

Почему на мете отключены сниппеты? На metaEnSO они доступны.

Comment: Зачем? Где они будут использоваться?

Comment: @NickVolynkin 1. Например, для [этого](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1744/178988). 2. А на metaEnSO они для чего используются? 3. Из них можно сделать [сворачиваемые спойлеры](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476703/178988).

Comment: @NickVolynkin там, где ["Крутой багрепорт"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4526/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment15745_4526)

Comment: @alexolut я давно плюсанул. Но для того, чтобы предложение было осмысленным, в нём должно быть обоснование, а не просто "хотим фичу, потому что у других есть".: )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну теперь-то обоснование есть. Надо только его в текущий вопрос вписать, имхо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сниппеты теперь работают на Мете!

<sub>P.S. Я написал этот ответ, т.к. считаю, что любой вопрос с установленным тегом [статус-*] должен подразумевать наличие ответа. См. [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4738/176217).</sub>