# Альтернативная логика удаления вопросов с Меты

Tags: предложение, удаление-вопросов, мета

Недавно искал свой старый вопрос, но не смог его найти, т.к. он оказался в списке удаленных. Ссылку на него удалось получить через список недавно удалённых вопросов в профиле:

> `https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/{ваш_id}`

Если у вас достаточно репутации, то вы можете найти его по [ссылке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3858/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0). Для полноты картины приведу скриншот:

> [image: скрин вопроса]

Как мне кажется, хорошо бы видеть этот вопрос на Мета сайте, хотя бы для возможности закрытия других подобных как дубликат. Удалять вопросы с Меты вообще сомнительно на основании одного лишь голосования, которое по сути является согласием/не согласием с выдвигаемым предложением как это сказано в описании метки [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5):

> Вопрос-предложение, описывающий идею новой или изменение существующей функциональности и поведения сайта. Для таких вопросов голоса «за» и «против» обозначают согласие или несогласие с предложением, а не качество или полезность вопроса.

Текущее моё предложение будет в том, что такие вопросы нельзя давать Духу на съедение. Т.е. нужна альтернативная логика для автоматического удаления вопросов на Мете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы при установке метки [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) писался бы поясняющий ответ, то вероятно, вопрос не попал бы под удаление. И в таком случае особая обработка вопросов на Мете была бы не нужна.